# Button change font family in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to change the font family of the button. I tried to change it trying this code:

```
Button txt = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "sfont.ttf");
txt.setTypeface(font);
```

but I am getting an error, and if I ignored it the app crashes every time.

This is the Layout XML code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<TextView

    android:text="@string/enter"
    android:textColor="#000"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:id="@+id/**button1**"text1
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:padding="20dp" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/**text1**" button1
    android:padding="30dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/entenbut"
    />
```

> PROBLEM SOLVED There was a problem in the XML code
>   Thanks everyone :)

Comment: would you mind sharing with us the stacktrace of the exception ?

Comment: sorry but how can I get the stacktrace of the exception? it is my first application :)

Comment: check the content of logcat

Comment: this is it
you can see it in the preview:

https://app.box.com/s/zst4c76cwzwiteqq5tdtvcvy7sgleeyc

Comment: why are you casting `AppCompatTextView` to `Button`?

Comment: I don't know exactly, I put the button from the widgets and I changed the string. that is all what I did do :)
I am trying to have a button with a text that lead me to another layout.
is there a way to fix that?

Comment: would you mind posting the layout, you are using ?

Comment: this is the layout
https://app.box.com/s/irovxwnf8znpr7czlnmlivbhrv3enegv

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a folder named "Assets" in your folder "src" (if you use Android Studio) and use:

```
Typeface tfFutura = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "sfont.ttf");
```

An observation: look if in your file are "TTF" or "ttf". I had problems with it.

Comment: no it is working, I can edit the font family for the TextView with the same code, but not the button

Comment: Please show the stacktrace Log. You can get him in the logcat when the error happens.

Comment: try look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17246695/android-widget-button-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-edittext     or      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12465551/android-widget-textview-cannot-be-cast-to-android-widget-button

Comment: I am trying to clean my project :)

Comment: Click Build > Clean Project

Comment: no, that didn't work i still having this:

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView cannot be cast to android.widget.Button

Comment: Your button use R.id.button1, but your Button in xml the use "@+id/text1"

Comment: how a bout external android fonts?

Answer (score 1):

In android studio there is not directory "src" but there is "res".
to create asset directory,first right click on the "app" then:
new -> Folder -> Assets Folder. after this,copy fonts to this directory.
[click here for more info](http://www.101apps.co.za/index.php/articles/using-custom-fonts-in-your-android-apps.html)

Comment: Thank you! The article was exactly what I was looking for.